The inverse function of $p(x)=\frac{1}{1+f(x)}$ in terms of $f^{-1}$
The problem:
$f$ is a one-to-one function with inverse $f^{-1}$. Calculate the inverse of the function $p(x)=\frac{1}{1+f(x)}$ in terms of $f^{-1}$.
The solution:
$p^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}-1)$
What I have tried:
$x=p(y)$, $y=p^{-1}(x)$
$$\begin{align*}p(x)=\frac{1}{1+f(x)} &\iff p(x)(1+f(x))=1 \\
&\iff f(x)=\frac{1}{p(x)}-1 \Rightarrow f(y)=\frac{1}{p(y)}-1 \\
&\iff f^{-1}(f(y))=f^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}-1) \\
&\iff y=f^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}-1) \iff p^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(\frac{1}{x}-1)\end{align*}$$
My question:
I do get the right answer, but I am unsure if my method is right. Did I do it right?

Your method looks fine to me - just be careful of when $p$ or $x$ equal $0$.

If you start with defining the domain and codomain of the function, you can write a more clear proof. Let $ p: \mathbb{R} \setminus {  x_1 } \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} \setminus {  0 } $ where $ f(x_1) = -1 $. For this domain and codomain, the function $ p $ is bijective since $ f $ is bijective.  Now, $ p^{-1}: \mathbb{R} \setminus {  0 } \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \setminus {  x_1 } $ which can be shown with your method since $ p(x) \neq 0 $ you can divide by $ p(x) $ and since $ f(x) \neq -1 $ you can divide by $ 1 + f(x) $.

It is very good. You should however not write $y=p^{-1}(x)$ at the beginning, since you have not proved that $p$ has an inverse yet.

Since you have not proved that $p$ has an inverse, you should not use $x=p^{-1}(y)$ at the beginning. You could show that $p$ has an inverse by showing it is injective and surjective, or do this work at the back, and start by directly claiming $p^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}\left(\frac1y-1\right)$ is a two-sided inverse.

Another method is to note that $p=g\circ f$ where $g(x)=1/(1+x)$. Now, $g$ is invertible with inverse $g^{-1}(y)=1/y-1$. (I am omitting the domains and codomains, which should have been done in the original question too.) So,
$$p^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}\left(\frac1y-1\right)$$
Hope this helps. :)
